# Signal from Microphone Feeds Into Headphones when Recording and Wearing Headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, sound-card

I'm wearing headphones and also recording myself at the same time, via a capture tool (e.g. Movavi Video Recorder) and a microphone (either a Web Camera mic or an external mic, such as Shure).

The problem is that my speech feeds into the headphones from the mic, so I hear myself talk in my headphones. The goal is to completely separate my recorded speech from what's playing in my headphones.

The Web Camera Mic or the External Mic are plugged in as USB devices.

```
OS: Windows 10 

Soundcard: Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 (USB)

Mic: Shure (USB) or Logitech Web Camera Mic (USB)
```

Comment: Please add an OS tag.

Comment: Suspect you mean fade not feed.

Comment: This is done in the sound options in control panel. I think it varies a little based on drivers but there are levels or an option like “listen to this device,” that can be adjusted.